# How to design REST APIi Route for this ternary association?

Tags: rest, api, django-rest-framework, restful-architecture

Consider the following database scheme :

- User (id, username, firstname, lastname, .....)
- Group (id, name) // 3 entries administrator, approver or issuer
- Project(id, name, launchdate, ....)

with a ternary association relating the three previous entities:

- Membership(user_id, group_id, project_id)

I need to create a route to change the group for a specific user in a specific project.

**What is the best RESTful Architecture to design this route?**

```
First draft : PUT : api/membership/user_id/project_id/group_id

This route associate group with group_id to user if it doesn't exist and remove it if it's associated
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best RestfullArchitecture to design this route.

Likely by exposing a membership resource

```
POST: /api/membership/
{
    'user': ...,
    'group': ...,
    'project': ...,
}
```

and

```
DELETE: /api/membership/{pk}
```

Alternatively, you could also create a "real" Group that would be linked to a projet and with the name among "administrator", "approver" or "issuer" and add users to them.

Comment: for an SPA this makes a lot of front overhead like managin memberships primary keys

Comment: Which is why I added an alternative option which makes more sense in the long term.

Comment: Conslusion: violating restfull constraints can make life much easier when dealing with SPA's

Comment: Bypassing constraints always makes life easier until the point you realize that easy is different from simple and start bringing back the constraints :)

Comment: about maintainability I have a good idea about system evolution and this route will never be used in another context.